# Как узнать имя файла по URL если Content-Disposition отсутствует?

Tags: php, файлы, curl

Как в php можно узнать имя файла, если есть только его URL?

Сейчас я делаю запрос через CURL и ищу имя файла в Content-Disposition. Но не у всех файлов в заголовках прописан Content-Disposition. Пример такого URL: https://btweb-assets.bittorrent.com/installer/BitTorrentWeb.dmg. Как еще можно определить имя?

Теоретически можно было бы вырезать имя из самого URL с помощью basename. Но некоторые URL "редиректные" и в них не прописано имя файла. Пример такого URL: https://download-hr.utorrent.com/track/beta/endpoint/utserver/os/linux-i386-debian-7-0.

Код, на котором тренируюсь, здесь: https://phpsandbox.io/n/small-wildflower-em17-wdmzb

Comment: никак не узнать.

Comment: А как браузер это делает?

Comment: тоже никак не делает, в вашем примере дебиана content-disposition прописан. либо пытаться из ссылки концовку вытащить, как вы и написали. других вариантов нет.

Comment: Понял, спасибо.